# How do you construct a WinSCP URL to launch PuTTY from a browser using a certificate?

Tags: putty, winscp

Using the WinSCP URL format, I can launch PuTTY, but I would like to use a certificate connection.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [WinSCP advanced URL syntax](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/session_url). Or even easier, use [WinSCP GUI to generate the URL](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_generateurl#url) with a private key or certificate:

```
ssh://user;x-publickeyfile=C%3A%255CUsers%255Cuser%255Ccertificates%255Ccertificate.ppk@example.com/
```

Comment: Brillant, exactly the help I needed, Thank you!!!